# Using a for loop nested in a while loop in r

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop

Experiment:'X is a binomial of five trials and p = 0.5, where X is the number of heads. Ysample is a binomial of X trials and p=0.5, where Ysample is the number of heads.'
T is the number of times the experiment is repeated until the value of Ysample>=3.
This is the code:

```
while (Ysample[i]<3){
length(X)=n
    length(Y)=n
    X=c(1:n)
    Y=c(1:n)
    i=1
    X[i]=sum(rbinom(5,1,0.5))
    Ysample[i]=sum(rbinom(X[i],1,0.5))
    i=i+1
    }
    T=n
```

I am unsure why it is not working and why no matter how many times I run it I always get T=10000?

Comment: Please do the favor of adding an appropriate language tab at the bottom of your posts, e.g. c, c++, php, ...  It's a waste time for people to have to open this up to see what language you are writing in.  Thanks.

Comment: The poster did add a language tab; r.  Although it should have been capitalized...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this what you want?

```
T <- 0
Ysample <- 0

while( Ysample < 3 )
{
    X <- sum( rbinom( 5, 1, 0.5 ) )
    Ysample <- sum( rbinom( X, 1, 0.5 ) )
    T <- T + 1
}

cat( "T =  ", T, "\n\n" )
```

Answer (score 1):

Check what you are setting n to.  T is simply set to n at the end of the loop.  It isn't computed or anything.

Also, you may want to consider using higher order functions; while R can handle loops, it does much better without them, and it's more idiomatic R to use higher order functions and the default "vectorizing" behavior of operations.